# Airbnb-DeepLinkDispatch without Activities

Tags: android, deep-linking, conductor

I'm trying to use [deepLinkDispatch](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch) lib without activities ([Conductor](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor)). I have only one activity in my project, and the others screens are Controllers. When I try to map my controller with `@DeepLink("xxx://test")`.

I get the error:

```
com.sample.test/com.sample.test.feature.form.view.controller.HostFormController}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Of course not because It's not an Activity :P

```
@DeepLink("xxx://test")
class HostFormController : com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Controller{
}
```

Any idea how to use deepLink without activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeepLinkDispatch is unfortunately only for Activities. You're not going to get it to work with any style of single-Activity architecture, whether it be Fragments, Conductor, or raw Views. There are several other libs that give more flexibility, and it's also not that hard to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my idea. Also, I found this one. It seems to fit with single-activity architecture. https://docs.urbanairship.com/tutorials/api/android/deep-linking/

Comment: @EricKuck what other libraries do you recommend for a Conductor-style architecture?

Comment: @DouglasMesquita  have you found solution manually or other lib?